# Can I tell SQL Server to "do something" when a connection is closed?

Tags: sql-server, locking

Can I tell SQL Server to "do something" (e.g. release an *application-level lock*) when the connection is closed for whatever reason?

---

**Background**: I want to lock a record *on the application level*, not on the database level. However, I'm having trouble releasing the lock when the application crashes. Basically, I am implementing the following algorithm in my application:

```
function editRecord(recordId):
    begin transaction
    if (select lockedBy from myTable where id = recordId) is not empty:
        commit
        show "Sorry, record already in use by ..."
    else
        update myTable set lockedBy = current_user() where id = recordId
        commit
        show UI window to let user edit and update record
        update myTablet set lockedBy = empty where id = recordId
```

I'm trying to find out if there is an easy way to get rid of the application-level lock when the connection crashes.

Comment: What if the connection doesn't end, but the user has gone to lunch?

Comment: Is there a field that shows when a lock was obtained?

Comment: Have you considered adopting an architecture that uses [`sp_getapplock`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189823%28v=sql.110%29.aspx) instead of your own table-based locking mechanism?

Comment: Seems like a SO question. Wanting SQL Server to affect a change at the app layer also seems in reverse. The app needs to handle the app crash / app lock.

Comment: @JonSeigel: Thanks, I did not know about sp_getapplock. It looks like a combination of sp_getapplock and APPLOCK_TEST should solve this problem nicely. Might I convince you to put that into an answer?

Comment: @AaronBertrand: Then the resource might stay locked.

Comment: @ThomasRushton: No, but using a heartbeat/timeout is one of the workarounds I have considered.

Comment: @Heinzi exactly, I would think that solving *that* problem would go along with solving *this* problem.

Comment: @AaronBertrand: It's not a problem. If the user goes to lunch, an administrator has to close his session and the user gets a good scolding. This is a critical part of the application, so pessimistic locking is by design.

Comment: Looking at the code again, if you need to record the user who locked the record, `sp_getapplock` will only complicate things. I think you can still do as stated in the question; all you need is to use the correct locking hints and isolation levels.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SQL Server provides a built-in mechanism to support application locking. The locks supported are Shared, Update, IntentShared, IntentExclusive, and Exclusive. Deadlock detection is also built-in, though application lock deadlocks do not terminate the active transaction - you need to check the result code returned from the system procedure call. Books Online documentation:

[APPLOCK_MODE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189749.aspx)
[APPLOCK_TEST](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178647.aspx)
[sp_getapplock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189823.aspx)
[sp_releaseapplock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178602.aspx)

Locks associated with the session are automatically released when the session is logged out.

*<sub>Community Wiki answer generated from a question comment by @JonSeigel</sub>*